# Partition into antichains

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, infinite-combinatorics

I've read that the following statement is a  result of Balcar, but I am unable to find a reference or a proof:

Theorem: If $\kappa\ge \lambda$ are infinite cardinals, then $[\kappa]^{<\lambda}$ can be partitioned into $2^{<\lambda}$-many antichains. (Here an ``antichain'' is a family of $\subset$-incomparable elements)

Background information:
I've read this statement in a handwritten note of Zoltan Szentmiklossy. He proved that if $X$ is a regular topological space and the cardinality of $X$ is smaller than the first strongly inaccessible cardinal, then $X$  has a Noetherian base, i.e. a base which does not contain an infinite $\subset$-increasing chain. In the proof he uses that Theorem. But he wrote that note 30 years ago, it was lost and then he found it just a few years ago.

Comment: At least $\lambda=\omega$ is easy, since distinct size $n$ subsets are incomparable.

Comment: I've read this statement in a handwritten note of Zoltan Szentmiklossy. He proved that if $X$ is a regular topological space and the cardinality of $X$ is smaller than the first strongly inaccessible cardinal, then $X$ has a Noetherian base, i.e. a base which does not contain an infinite $\subset$-increasing chain.  In the proof he uses that Theorem.  But he wrote that note 30 years ago, it was lost and then found just a few years ago.

Comment: @LajosSoukup: That theorem of Szentmiklossy about the Noetherian base is very interesting. You may be aware of this already, but it implies that Telgarsky's conjecture about Banach-Mazur games fails for spaces smaller than the first inaccessible. Is the proof written down anyplace where I can read it?

Comment: @WillBrian I know that Rastislav Telgarsky wrote a number of papers about Banach-Mazur games. What is "Telgarsky's conjecture" and which paper is it in?

Comment: The conjecture I'm thinking of states that for every $k \in \mathbb N$, there is a (regular) space $X_k$ such that the nonempty player has a winning $k$-tactic, but no winning $(k+1)$-tactic, in the Banach-Mazur game on $X_k$. This is stated in Telgarsky's ``$50th$ anniversary" paper. The conjecture is known to be consistently false: it fails under GCH$+\square$. (The proof uses a generalization of Davies trees, which I suppose you'd appreciate.) The result of Szentmiklossy you stated would give a different proof that this is consistently false: it fails if there are no inaccessible cardinals.

Comment: @WillBrian Thanks. I think you mean "a winning $(k+1)$-tactic but but not a winning $k$-tactic."

Comment: @bof: Oops -- yes, it makes more sense that way :)

Comment: @bof: Thank you for your advice. I added background information to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have a reference; I hope the following is a proof.

If $\alpha$ is an ordinal, let $\binom\kappa\alpha=\{X\subseteq\kappa:\operatorname{tp}X=\alpha\}$ where $\operatorname{tp}X$ is the order type of $X$; let $\kappa_\alpha=2^{|\alpha|}$; if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, choose an injection $h_\alpha:^{\operatorname{cf}\alpha}(\alpha\times\kappa_\alpha)\to\kappa_\alpha$. For each limit ordinal $\gamma$ choose a cofinal sequence $\langle\beta_{\xi,\gamma}:\xi\lt\operatorname{cf}\gamma\rangle$ in $\gamma$.

It will suffice to show that, for each ordinal $\alpha$, the set $\binom\kappa\alpha$ is the union of $\kappa_\alpha$ antichains; *i.e.*, that there is a function $f:\binom\kappa\alpha\to\kappa_\alpha$ such that
$$X,Y\in\binom\kappa\alpha,\ X\subsetneqq Y\implies f(X)\ne f(Y).$$
Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal, and suppose $f(X)$ has already been defined for $X\in\bigcup_{\beta\lt\alpha}\binom\kappa\beta$. Consider any set $X\in\binom\kappa\alpha$.

If $\alpha=\beta+1$, let $f(X)=f(X\setminus\{\max X\})$. If $X,Y\in\binom\kappa\alpha$ and $X\subsetneqq Y$, let $X'=X\setminus\{\max X\}$ and $Y'=Y\setminus\{\max Y\}$; then $X',Y'\in\binom\kappa\beta$ and $X'\subsetneqq Y'$, so $f(X)=f(X')\neq f(Y')=f(Y)$.

If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, let $\gamma=\sup X$ and let
$$f(X)=h_\alpha(\langle(\operatorname{tp}(X\cap\beta_{\xi,\gamma}),f(X\cap\beta_{\xi,\gamma})):\xi\lt\operatorname{cf}\gamma=\operatorname{cf}\alpha\rangle).$$
If $X,Y\in\binom\kappa\alpha$ and $X\subsetneqq Y$, let $\gamma=\sup X=\sup Y$; then $X\cap\beta_{\xi,\gamma}\subsetneqq Y\cap\beta_{\xi,\gamma}$ for some $\xi\lt\operatorname{cf}\gamma$. Let $X_\xi=X\cap\beta_{\xi,\gamma}$ and $Y_\xi=Y\cap\beta_{\xi,\gamma}$; then either $\operatorname{tp}X_\xi\lt\operatorname{tp}Y_\xi$, or else $\operatorname{tp}X_\xi=\operatorname{tp}Y_\xi$ and $f(X_\xi)\ne f(Y_\xi)$. Since $h_\alpha$ is injective, it follows that $f(X)\ne f(Y)$.